# Getting Integrity check failed while installing a local npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have a local React library/Project say Components. Which i have to use in my main Project DEMO.

1. First I pack my Components project and create tar ball file.
2. I am trying to install the packed tarball in DEMO. It is throwing Integrity check failed
   error as in package-lock.json there is different integrity value for this library(Components) is mentioned.

Is there a way to disable this integrity check in npm or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try to delete package-lock.json and retry npm install ?

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` ??

Comment: What command is throwing "integrity check failed"?